# regex to remove multiple comma and spaces from string in javascript

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a string like

```
var str=" , this,  is a ,,, test string , , to find regex,,in js.  , ";
```

in which there are multiple spaces in beginning,middle and end of string with commas. i need this string in

```
var str="this is a test string to find regex in js.";
```

i found many regex in forum removing spaces , commas separately but i could not join them to remove both.

Please give explanation of regex syntex to if possible .

Thanks in advance

Comment: _"Please give explanation of regex syntex to if possible"_ - Have you looked at [MDN's regex page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions) or http://www.regular-expressions.info/?

Comment: in other string i need multiple space replaced and multiple comma with single comma, like var str=", this is to replace ,, multiple comma and space. ,"; where i need to replace comma from start and end of string , replace multiple spaces with one space , and multiple comma within string to single comma .
as var result_str="this is to replace ,multiple comma and space";

Comment: @Dashrath Could you put that in your question please? And when should the comma not be completely removed?

Answer (score 44, accepted):

You can just replace every space and comma with space then trim those trailing spaces:

```
var str=" , this,  is a ,,, test string , , to find regex,,in js.  , ";
res = str.replace(/[, ]+/g, " ").trim();
```

[jsfiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Unknown008/SKPD4/)

Comment: Thx for a good answer, but what's the real difference between str.replace(/[, ]+/g, " ").trim() and str.replace(/[, ]+/g, " ") without a trim() ? Just checked, results are same (or may be i mistaken somewhere?)

Comment: @NikolayTalanov Spaces at the beginning and end, if you had `****hello***` it'd end up as `*hello*`. Using `trim()` eliminates this. Note using * to mean space here for clarity...

Comment: @Lloyd Exactly right :)

Answer (score 5):

you can use reg ex for this

```
/[,\s]+|[,\s]+/g

var str= "your string here";
//this will be new string after replace
str = str.replace(/[,\s]+|[,\s]+/g, 'your string here');
```

[RegEx Explained and Demo](http://regex101.com/r/kU9cN3)

Comment: You should make use of the replace function on regex101 :)

Answer (score 4):

Try something like this:

```
var new_string = old_string.replace(/[, ]+/g,' ').trim();
```

The regex is simply `[, ]+` if we were to break this down the `\s` means ANY whitespace character and `,` is a literal comma. The `[]` is a character set (think array) and the `+` means one or more matches.

We throw in a `/g` on the end so that it does a global search and replace, otherwise it'd just do it for one match only.

Comment: this is producing result as new_string="thisisteststringtofindregexinjs";

Comment: Oops my bad, fixed it now I think.

Comment: It just replaces commas by spaces, resulting in a string with several spaces between the words.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to use

```
str.replace(/,/g," ");
```

The 'g' is the key, you may need to use `[,]`