# replace and submit the text only letters without space and period comma and other symbols

Tags: javascript, html, regex

every one I have a form like this, I have to submit and replace the name text only letters,,which is no comma no space or &&%%$$**,??...etc.

[image]

> myform.html

```
<script>
function fixInput(event) {
  name = name.replace(/[^a-z]+/gi, '');
  $("input[type=submit]")
}
</script>

<h1>Create a Thing</h1>
<form role="form" action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<input type='hidden' name='csrfmiddlewaretoken' value='CiTMjJgFuTMRatFsQRBUT6z8JuyRhe2g' />
<p><label for="id_name">Name:</label> <input id="id_name" maxlength="255" name="name" type="text" /></p>
<p><label for="id_image">Image:</label> <input id="id_image" name="image" type="file" /></p>
<p><label for="id_description">Description:</label> <textarea cols="40" id="id_description" name="description" rows="10">
</textarea></p>
 <input type="submit"  value="Submit" />
</form>
```

and I am trying to use javascript and regex to remove and replace the text and submit input the

> Name

which is

> id="id_name"

I just [figure ou](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19245963/5678590)t this js and regex can do it,,,however I do not konw how to put it together in to my form. I have to replace the text without space and ,.?*& ...etc. for example I have to let the text stay all together tight without space "this,  is a ,,,?" --> "thisisa"

thanks for who like to answer

Comment: `str = str.replace(/[\s,]/g,'')`

Comment: Rajesh gave the answer, albeit you should really have a look at the Mozilla Doc which is pretty complete in every aspect of Web development, so are the regex  : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp

Comment: thank you very much,,it can remove all space and punctuation, however, I still need unicode if I type in other language

Comment: finally I use "var rx = /[!-#%-*,-/\:;?@\[-\]_\{\} ]+/gi;" and solve it, thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably want to fix input "on fly"

```
function fixInput(event) {
  var rx = /[^a-z]+/gi;
  event.target.value = event.target.value.replace(rx, '');
}
document.getElementById('id_name').addEventListener('keyup',  fixInput);
document.getElementById('id_name').addEventListener('change',  fixInput);
```

This is working example with your HTML https://jsfiddle.net/6uhLaL3f/1/

Comment: I just post the new html code on it,however it did not work, can you check it, thank you,,

Comment: thank you very much,,it can remove all space and punctuation, however, I still need unicode if I type in other language,  
finally I use "var rx = /[!-#%-*,-/\:;?@[-]_\{\} ]+/gi;" and solve it, thank you

Answer (score 1):

If I well understand, you want to remove everything that is not a letter:

```
var new_string = str.replace(/[^a-z]+/gi, '');
```

Comment: thanks, this can make the text replace only letter, however, I do not how can   I put it in my html, I just post the new  html code  on it, can you check it, thank you

Comment: @CcL: I'm not so good at HTML, but you could add a listener on input box exit.