# Comma-separated numbers in input in Javascript

Tags: javascript, regex, decimal, nan

In the following process, there is no problem when the number 9999 is entered.

However, when entered as 9,999, the result is NaN.

How do I make an edit? I need to be able to use comic numbers.

I take the percentage of the number entered in input and print it to the input below.

```js
function yirmibes() {
  num1 = document.getElementById("firstNumber").value;
  document.getElementById("result").value = (num1 / 100) * 25;
}

function elli() {
  num1 = document.getElementById("firstNumber").value;
  document.getElementById("result").value = (num1 / 100) * 50;
}

function format(input) {
  var nStr = input.value + '';  
  nStr = nStr.replace(/\,/g, "");
  x = nStr.split('.');
  x1 = x[0];
  x2 = x.length > 1 ? '.' + x[1] : '';  
  var rgx = /(\d+)(\d{3})/;
  while (rgx.test(x1)) {
    x1 = x1.replace(rgx, '$1' + ',' + '$2');
  }
  input.value = x1 + x2;
}
```

```html
Number: <input type="text" id="firstNumber" onkeyup="format(this)" />
<br/><br/>
<input type="button" onClick="yirmibes()" Value="25%" />
<input type="button" onClick="elli()" Value="50%" />
<br/><br /> The Result is :
<input type="text" id="result" Value="" />
```

Answer (score 1):

Remove comma when calculating result:

```
function yirmibes()
{
  num1 = document.getElementById("firstNumber").value.replace(',', '');
  document.getElementById("result").value = (num1 / 100) * 25;
}
function elli()
{
  num1 = document.getElementById("firstNumber").value.replace(',', '');
  document.getElementById("result").value = (num1 / 100) * 50;
}
```

Comment: *@Alex* What about if more than one comma. `.replace(',', '')` it will work only first comma in integer if there is more than one comma then NAN result will appear.

Answer (score 0):

You need to parse the input value as float if you want to accept comma-values, otherwise it will be text and you can not calculate with text-values :)

If the numbers will only be full numbers and you want to strip out a thousand seperator a parseInt should do the job, otherwise you could replace all non-number characters, or better use an `input type="number"` to only allow the input of numbers

parseFloat see: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseFloat

input type number see: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/number

Answer (score 0):

Comma-separated numbers is a `String` not a `Number` in Javascript.

**So you can't count a `String` with `Number`, there is why you got a `NaN`.**

There are many ways can achieve what you want, but the important thing is that don't use a String to count a Number.

In my view, you can use the `replace()` to remove the comma from your input value, and then use `parseInt()` to get an correct number. Like this :

```
var num1 = document.getElementById("firstNumber").value;
num1 = parseFloat(num1);
```

Answer (score 0):

This code works, thanks to Alex S. I just tested it on w3schools.

```
function yirmibes()
{
  num1 = document.getElementById("firstNumber").value.replace(/,/g,'');
  document.getElementById("result").value = (num1 / 100) * 25;
}
function elli()
{
  num1 = document.getElementById("firstNumber").value.replace(/,/g, '');
  document.getElementById("result").value = (num1 / 100) * 50;
}

function format(input) {
  var nStr = input.value + '';  
  nStr = nStr.replace(/\,/g, "");
  x = nStr.split('.');
  x1 = x[0];
  x2 = x.length > 1 ? '.' + x[1] : '';  
  var rgx = /(\d+)(\d{3})/;
  while (rgx.test(x1)) {
    x1 = x1.replace(rgx, '$1' + ',' + '$2');
  }
  input.value = x1 + x2;
}
```

```html
Number: <input type="text" id="firstNumber" onkeyup="format(this)" />
<br/><br/>
<input type="button" onClick="yirmibes()" Value="25%" />
<input type="button" onClick="elli()" Value="50%" />
<br/><br /> The Result is :
<input type="text" id="result" Value="" />
```

Comment: `.replace(',','')` this method will not work if more than one comma. So there is need to use *Regex expression* and *.trim()* method.

Comment: @RaeeshAlam here is the updated solution. .replace(/,/g,'')

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `.replace()` method and `.trim()` method for removing comma from *inserted value*.

**Reference:** https://stackoverflow.com/a/19245975/7052927

```js
function yirmibes() {
    num1 = document.getElementById("firstNumber").value.replace(/[, ]+/g, "").trim();
    document.getElementById("result").value = (num1 / 100) * 25;
}

function elli() {
    num1 = document.getElementById("firstNumber").value.replace(/[, ]+/g, "").trim();
    document.getElementById("result").value = (num1 / 100) * 50;
}

function format(input) {
    var nStr = input.value + '';
    nStr = nStr.replace(/\,/g, "");
    x = nStr.split('.');
    x1 = x[0];
    x2 = x.length > 1 ? '.' + x[1] : '';
    var rgx = /(\d+)(\d{3})/;
    while (rgx.test(x1)) {
        x1 = x1.replace(rgx, '$1' + ',' + '$2');
    }
    input.value = x1 + x2;
}
```

```html
Number: <input type="text" id="firstNumber" onkeyup="format(this)" />
<br /><br />
<input type="button" onClick="yirmibes()" Value="25%" />
<input type="button" onClick="elli()" Value="50%" />
<br /><br /> The Result is :
<input type="text" id="result" Value="" />
```